# How to split one column with different line length into multiple in R

Tags: r

My file has no headers, it is in one column and every 21st row is longer than the rest. Therefore, it doesn't read the rest of the line in those rows. The only way I've made it work is to put in a line with headers directly in the file, but I hope to avoid this, as I have many files and it will cause trouble later on as I have to combine these files afterwards. So far, I've tried different things like `strsplit()` command. Here is a piece of my data:

```
1533541940,90,123,0,656.45,13.00,50496,0.0000,-1,-1,-1,-1
1533541941,90,124,0,656.45,13.00,50496,0.0000,-1,-1,-1,-1
1533541941,90,125,0,656.45,13.00,50496,0.0000,-1,-1,-1,-1
1533541944,90,126,0,656.45,13.00,50496,0.0000,-1,-1,-1,-1,#,#,28.00,41.00,#,0,0.60,1.60,#,496,#,450,16,46560,16,173800,#,28.41,45.93,1017.19,135383.00
1533541945,90,127,0,658.06,13.00,50620,0.0000,-1,-1,-1,-1
1533541945,90,128,0,658.06,13.00,50620,0.0000,-1,-1,-1,-1
```

I only have little experience with programming, therefore I ask you please if you can answer me with semi "plain English" as I don't understand much of the programming language yet. I appreciate any help I can get, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

this should do the trick

```
res <- read.csv(text = "1533541940,90,123,0,656.45,13.00,50496,0.0000,-1,-1,-1,-1
1533541941,90,124,0,656.45,13.00,50496,0.0000,-1,-1,-1,-1
           1533541941,90,125,0,656.45,13.00,50496,0.0000,-1,-1,-1,-1
           1533541944,90,126,0,656.45,13.00,50496,0.0000,-1,-1,-1,-1,#,#,28.00,41.00,#,0,0.60,1.60,#,496,#,450,16,46560,16,173800,#,28.41,45.93,1017.19,135383.00
           1533541945,90,127,0,658.06,13.00,50620,0.0000,-1,-1,-1,-1
           1533541945,90,128,0,658.06,13.00,50620,0.0000,-1,-1,-1,-1", header = FALSE)
```

you can supply the path to the file as an argument to `read.csv` also

output:

```
          V1 V2  V3 V4     V5 V6    V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21 V22 V23 V24 V25
1 1533541940 90 123  0 656.45 13 50496  0 -1  -1  -1  -1          NA  NA      NA  NA  NA      NA      NA  NA
2 1533541941 90 124  0 656.45 13 50496  0 -1  -1  -1  -1          NA  NA      NA  NA  NA      NA      NA  NA
3 1533541941 90 125  0 656.45 13 50496  0 -1  -1  -1  -1          NA  NA      NA  NA  NA      NA      NA  NA
4 1533541944 90 126  0 656.45 13 50496  0 -1  -1  -1  -1   #   #  28  41   #   0 0.6 1.6   # 496   # 450  16
5 1533541945 90 127  0 658.06 13 50620  0 -1  -1  -1  -1          NA  NA      NA  NA  NA      NA      NA  NA
6 1533541945 90 128  0 658.06 13 50620  0 -1  -1  -1  -1          NA  NA      NA  NA  NA      NA      NA  NA
    V26 V27    V28 V29   V30   V31     V32    V33
1    NA  NA     NA        NA    NA      NA     NA
2    NA  NA     NA        NA    NA      NA     NA
3    NA  NA     NA        NA    NA      NA     NA
4 46560  16 173800   # 28.41 45.93 1017.19 135383
5    NA  NA     NA        NA    NA      NA     NA
6    NA  NA     NA        NA    NA      NA     NA
```

if you do not need the data after column V12

```
res < res[,1:12]
```

Update - answer to the question in the comments:

```
res2 <- readLines("res.csv", encoding = "utf-8") 
res2 <- strsplit(res2, ",") 
data.table::rbindlist(lapply(res2,
                             function(x) as.data.frame(matrix(x,
                                                              nrow = 1))),
                      fill = TRUE)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't:-( I get the same result as before when using it on my file as the first six rows are short. It works only when the number of short rows above the long row is six or less as set by default in R, which reads the first six lines and sets the column number from that. Hence, my problem...any other suggestion?

Comment: @Clueless I have updated the answer, please check if it performs good on your data.

Comment: And what if I do need the order of my data to stay as it is? How do I do then? My data is a time series, therefore, the order is very important. Can your modification be used then?

Comment: @Clueless I do not see how would the solution impede with the order of the data. It does not on the test data I used, but as I said it would be best if you checked on your own data which is not posted in the question (For instance I had no idea about the first six row limitation you posted in the first comment).

Answer (score 0):

you can do it automatically by using readlines() and read.csv():

```
read.csv(text= readLines("yourfile.csv", encoding = "utf-8"), header = F)
```

Edit: as mentioned in your comment, the number of columns is derived from the first six lines. To ensure you have all columns (and do not care about the order of your data), you can run:

```
# library(stringr)
a <- readLines("yourfile.csv", encoding = "utf-8", sep=",") #this will get all the data in the lines
b <- order(sapply(a, function(x){a <- str_count(x, ","); return(a)}),decreasing = T) # This will make sure the longest one will be first so you have the maximum nbr of columns
read.csv(text= a[b], header = F)
```

Comment: Also doesn't work when the number of rows above are more than six. It just lines up the longer rows underneath the others.

Comment: @Clueless, if you do not care about the order of your lines, you can use the following: `# library(stringr)
a <- readLines("yourfile.csv", encoding = "utf-8", sep=",")
b <- order(sapply(a, function(x){a <- str_count(x, ","); return(a)}),decreasing = T)
read.csv(text= a[b], header = F)`

Comment: Thanks, Arno, but the order of my lines are quite significant as they are a time series. Can I use your suggestion in a way that my lines keep their order?